# 18.04.4 Open applications in background

Tags: desktop-icons, background-process

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS , Kernel version Linux 5.3.0-28-generic.
I want the applications to open in the background whenever I click the application icons that are on the left pane.

For e.g. I open Atom, then IntelliJ and while I am editing texts in Atom, the IntelliJ window opens right in front and I have to press ALT + TAB to get Atom focus again. This is very annoying.

Can I get some help please so as to keep working in Atom and when I am done, I can click on the IntelliJ icon to bring IntelliJ in focus?

Comment: Funny others are annoyed when newly applications are opened behind current active window, Check comments here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084032/how-to-prevent-new-windows-from-stealing-focus

Comment: You may try `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-new-windows 'strict'`

Comment: 18.04.4 is a development version, and not yet released.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out "Focus Follows Mouse" GNOME extension at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/767/focus-follows-mouse/. You can also search there for other "focus" extensions that may better suit your needs.