# How do I get Ubuntu to switch to applications instead of notifications of 'appxxx is ready"

Tags: notification

In various, though not all, times when I choose an application all I get is a notification popup saying  'appname(whatever) is ready" rather then switching to it. Obviously even though it is already open, I want to go to it. this is the opposite to sometimes people get the application opening when they want it to run in the background.
Ubuntu 20.04 Wayland gdm3

Comment: latest example, in Firefox, cty-shift-y to bring up the downloads window. granted things were busy but  I ended up with three of those windows and none of the switched to it at the time. now that things are not so busy, it goes straight to it without the popup.

Comment: this also happens with midi files when clicking in Krusader, MuseScore application. lots of other times. almost as annoying as the snap updates are ready notificaitons. I have not ordered a hamburger or car detailing. Obviously I want to switch to it.

Comment: MuseScore and Firefox are snap apps... I am wondering if there is a connection here and a common source of user unfriendliness.

Comment: in Ubuntu Settings, Notifications, I de-selected MuseScore, and whilst I did not get the notification I did get the MuseScore startup flash screen, but did not get switched to it.

Comment: and now I do not even get the MuseScore flash screen

Comment: @pierrely Cloud you please [add](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1450034/edit) you comments to your question and maybe add a screen shot...

Comment: nope., it is clear enough as the extensions which fix the problem also state. and as they say, we get Ubuntu to work by extensions, not inclusion (or available obvious Settings)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing happens to me in Gnome when a window is presented in a different workspace then the active one. Are you using workspaces?

Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084032/how-to-prevent-new-windows-from-stealing-focus), which is sort of a reverse of your issue - see if any of the settings mentioned there are on by default on your system.

Try [this gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5612/focus-indicator/) see if focus isn't switched.

UPDATE: Or maybe this [other gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1236/noannoyance/).

Comment: focus indicator is 'not supported' unfortunately and also unsupported if probably what I need "steal my focus let windows steal the focus removes the annoying "window is ready '' notification and focus window..." also unupported is 'focus my window' and also unsupported is 'steal my focus'. BUT 'grand theft focus' is supported . that one worked, the bounty is yours. thanks. (and getting any extensions to work was a workaround in itself as tweaks no longer works. Extension Manager was needed.

Comment: he he , I was just able to upvote my own question to undo the rude unexplained downvote.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty and thanks for the explanation. glad you found a solution.

Comment: I've added an additional gnome extension that might ease the pain

Comment: thanks, I will stick to what is now working for now.