# Set application to "always on top"

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gui

I am using Ubuntu 23.10 and I would like to set an application, in my case CuteCom Serial Monitor, to be always on top. At the moment if my IDE is fullscreen I have to launch CuteCom from the dash and then after I return to the IDE and make some changes I have to relaunch Cutecom from the dash again.

If this is possible I can imagine it being useful for other applications too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just <kbd>right-click</kbd> on the titlebar of the window you want to keep on top and select *Always on Top* from the menu.

[image: screenshot displaying the Always on Top option]

Alternatively, if you prefer to not use the mouse, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd> and use the up and down arrows to select *Always on Top*.

Comment: And how do we modify the application startup icon to run in "Always on Top" mode, each time it is re-launched?

Comment: @FedKad I guess that you could change the `Exec=` line of the application's `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` to add `&& sleep 1 && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,above"` wrapped in `sh -c ""`. For example, to make Nautilus always on top when launched, you would change its `Exec=` line to `Exec=sh -c "nautilus --new-window %U && sleep 1 && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,above"`. You may have to adjust the `sleep` duration. Use `cp /usr/share/applications/application.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/` to copy an application's `.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applications/`.

Comment: @FedKad I think that this would also be nice as a new question and maybe someone could have a better approach than mine.

Answer (score 1):

From command line?  If so, you need `wmctrl`.
In it's most simple form:

```
xwin=$(xwininfo | grep -oP 'Window id: \K0x[0-9a-f]+'); wmctrl -i -r "$xwin" -b add,above
```

This could serve as a GUI version.
These are the dependencies you will need to install.

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool xprop wmctrl yad xbindkeys
```

```
#!/bin/bash

about_dialog() {
    yad --window-icon="help-faq" --title="About" --on-top --borders=10 --center --skip-taskbar --image="preferences-system-windows" --buttons-layout="center" --text-align=center --text="Always On Top!\n\nChange selected window's 'state' from\n'Below' to 'Above' &amp; Vice-versa.\n" --button=Close!application-exit!:0
}
export -f about_dialog

set_keybinding() {
    if [ ! -f ~/.ontop_tray_xkbrc ]; then
        current_binding='[none]'
    else
        current_binding=$(sed '2q;d' ~/.ontop_tray_xkbrc)
    fi

    remove_button='rm ~/.ontop_tray_xkbrc; echo "\"bash -c 'toggle_gnome'\"" > ~/.ontop_tray_xkbrc && xdotool windowkill window="cat /tmp/xwin_id_xkb" && bash -c set_keybinding'
    show_current=$(echo "$current_binding")

    yad --window-icon="input-keyboard" --borders="15" --on-top --skip-taskbar --title="Key Binding" \
        --text-align="center" --buttons-layout="center" --text="Current Binding\n$show_current\n" \
        --separator=" " --item-separator=" " --print-xid="/tmp/xwin_id_xkb" --form  \
        --field="Hold 1:":CB "Ctrl Alt Shift" \
        --field="Hold 2:":CB "Shift Ctrl Alt" \
        --field="Action:":entry "T" \
        --field=Remove-Binding:BTN "bash -c '$remove_button'" \
        --button=Confirm:0 \
        --button=Cancel:1 > /tmp/entries

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        exit 1
    fi

    entries=$(cut -d'|' -f1 < /tmp/entries)

    f1=$(echo "$entries" | awk '{print $1}')
    f2=$(echo "$entries" | awk '{print $2}')
    f3=$(echo "$entries" | awk '{print $3}')

    key_combo=$(echo "$f1+$f2+$f3" | tr ' ' '+')

    if [ ! -f ~/.ontop_tray_xkbrc ]; then
        echo "\"bash -c 'toggle_gnome'\"" > ~/.ontop_tray_xkbrc
    fi

    echo "$key_combo" > ~/.ontop_tray_xkbrc

    # Restart xbindkeys
    killall xbindkeys 2> /dev/null
    xbindkeys --file ~/.ontop_tray_xkbrc
}
export -f set_keybinding

tmp_error() {
    yad --skip-taskbar --on-top --window-icon="gtk-error" --title="Write Error" --image="gtk-error" \
        --button="Quit":1 \
        --text="Unable to write to /tmp\nCheck permissions for $USER."
    exit 1
}
export -f tmp_error

error_control() {
# Workaround:   Clicking OSK's enter-key will cause crosshair failure.
#                           wmctrl, xdotool & xprop—all fail with 'onboard' OSK.
    yad --skip-taskbar --on-top --window-icon="dialog-question" --title="Retry?" --image="dialog-question" \
        --button="Try Again":0 \
        --button="Quit":1 \
        --text="Failed to focus on the window.\nDo you want to retry?" \

    response=$?

    if [ $response -eq 0 ]; then
                select_window
    else
        exit 1
    fi
}
export -f error_control

select_window() {
        xdotool selectwindow > /tmp/xwin_id

        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            error_control
        fi

        if [ ! -f /tmp/xwin_id ]; then
        tmp_error
        fi

        wmctrl -i -r "$(sed '1q;d' /tmp/xwin_id)" -b add,above
}
export -f select_window

select_new() {
        wmctrl -i -r $(sed '1q;d' /tmp/xwin_id) -b remove,above
    rm /tmp/xwin_id
        select_window
}
export -f select_new

toggle_gnome() {
    toggle_xwin_id=$(</tmp/xwin_id)
    xprop -id "$toggle_xwin_id" > /tmp/xwin_state
    check_state=$(cat /tmp/xwin_state | grep -q "_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE")
    
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        wmctrl -i -r "$toggle_xwin_id" -b remove,above
    else
        wmctrl -i -r "$toggle_xwin_id" -b add,above
    fi
}
export -f toggle_gnome

select_window

# Tray Icon & Menu
yad --notification --skip-taskbar --image="go-top" \
    --command="bash -c 'about_dialog'" \
    --menu=" Toggle !bash -c 'toggle_gnome' \
    | Select !bash -c 'echo "1" >> /tmp/xwin_id; select_new' \
    | Keybind !bash -c 'set_keybinding' \
    | Exit !bash -c 'wmctrl -i -r $(sed '1q;d' /tmp/xwin_id) -b remove,above && killall yad'" \
--text="Always On Top!"

exit 0
```

It will prompt to choose a window. Right click the tray icon to: **Toggle** (on/off), **Select** different "Always On Top" window & **Keybind** to set hotkey for toggling.

Save to: `ontop_tray_icon.sh`
Change mode to executable: `chmod +x ontop_tray_icon.sh`
Usage: `./ontop_tray_icon.sh`

Comment: This seems a bit overkill since the always on top functionality is already builtin on GNOME, but may be useful for other DEs. However, the script in its current form doesn't work. You don't seem to call the `focus_window()` function somewhere. Also, your script uses `yad` and `wmctrl`, which are not installed by default, so you should add instructions for how to install them. You should also add instructions for how to run the script.

Comment: Okay.  I will do those things.  It's not a big deal to delete, but if it will help someone?  I'll even make it install the dependency's.

Comment: No, I didn't comment to make you delete the answer! Feel free to keep it as long as you make it work! Even if it is for your own learning, it is still useful and perfectly acceptable if it works at the end! Choice is always welcome! :)

Comment: It works after your last edit and even the option I mentioned in my answer shows as selected! However, I don't get any `yad` window. Also how can it be turned off so that the selected window becomes normal again?

Comment: Excellent!  Right click the tray icon to adjust it. 

Comment: You know what, I thought of a usecase where this could be really handy: have it as a keyboard shortcut that toggles the state of the currently active window. Assigning it to, say, `Super`+`T` it will be much faster to make a window stay on top than having to use the mouse. Excellent for people that would use this functionality a lot. Could you adjust your script to make it work that way?

Comment: I don't get a tray icon. Do you use GNOME?

Comment: Is it just the green liquid beaker?  I chose the big gold star for no particular reason.  Across versions, icon names vary some.  Use `yad-icon-browser` to find one you like and change "starred" in `--image="starred"` to the name in the icon browser.  And, yes sir, I'll add a toggle to the menu + key binding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150683/discussion-between-beastofcaerbannog-and-j-cravens).

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog Got it!  Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Is there a reason this code is constantly being edited?  Ask Ubuntu is not a code repository, you might want to consider putting your script on Github or a Gist or something instead of using Ask Ubuntu as a code repository.

Comment: @ThomasWard There is.  It's finished now.
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150683/discussion-between-beastofcaerbannog-and-j-cravens